# How to immediately show watch value while debugging Blazor webassembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor-webassembly, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to debug some code in a blazor webassembly code behind file. It mostly works as I am used to but for some reason it doesn't show the value but a function.

You can see this in this screenshot:

[image]

I'm using Visual Studio 17.5.0 Preview 1.0 and .net7

Is there any setting I have to adjust so it will directly show the value instead of the method name?

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls in Tools > Options > Debugging > General:
[image]

You can also see [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/71464) for more information.

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried this and it didnt do what I want

Comment: @SimonBalling Can you provide some code to help reproduce this problem? Also, do you have VS on your computer other than the preview version? You can test whether this method works in other versions, maybe this is a preview version problem.